# Congruence for Stirling Number of first kind $s(n,k)$ when $n$ is prime

Tags: combinatorics, prime-numbers, congruences, stirling-numbers

Let $s(n,k)$ be the Stirling numbers of first kind: $$\prod_{k=0}^{k=n-1}(x-k) =\sum_{k=0}^{k=n}s(n,k)x^k$$

> $p$ is prime $\iff$ for all $k\in\{2,..,p-1\}$,   $s(p,k)\equiv0\     
>  mod\ p $

How can this be demonstrated?

There is an analogous statement for the Stirling numbers of second kind ${n \brace k}$ which is quite easy to prove from the explicit formula $$k!{n \brace k}=(-1)^k\sum_{j=0}^{j=k}(-1)^j\binom{k}{j}j^n $$ 
But I do not know of an analogous explicit formula for the first kind...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work in the polynomial ring $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)[x]$: in that ring $x^{\underline p}=x^p-x$, since both polynomials are monic of degree $p$ and have roots $0,\ldots,p-1$. Now just equate coefficients to get the positive part of the result.

For the negative result, suppose that $n$ is not prime, let $p$ be a prime dividing $n$, and let $m=\frac{n}p$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
x^{\underline n}&=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x-i)=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\prod_{\ell=0}^{p-1}(x-kp-\ell)=\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\prod_{\ell=0}^{p-1}(x-\ell)\\\\
&=\left(x^{\underline p}\right)^m=\left(x^p-x\right)^m=x^m\left(x^{p-1}-1\right)^m\;,
\end{align*}$$

and it follows that $s(n,m)\equiv(-1)^m\not\equiv 0\pmod p$.

For many more results on congruences involving Stirling numbers of the first kind see Rhodes Peele, A.J. Radcliffe, and Herbert S. Wilf, [*Congruence problems involving Stirling numbers of the first kind*](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/31-1/peele.pdf) [PDF]. What I did here is a special case of results there.

Comment: very nice demonstration!  simple et beautiful.  Thanks for the paper. Actually, I think I have found another demonstration, very different from this one. I will post it as another answer.

Comment: @René: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another very different argument, which seems to work but only in one direction:$$x^{\underline n}=\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}(x-i)=(-1)^nn!\sum_{\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} {i.n_i=n}}\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}\frac{(-x)^{n_i}}{i^{n_i}n_i!}$$
The big sigma is over all the integer partitions of $n$, i.e. over all the n-uplets $(n_1,..,n_n), n_i\ge0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{i=n} {i.n_i=n}$

then $$s(n,k)=(-1)^{n+k}n!\sum\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}\frac{1}{i^{n_i}n_i!}$$ here the sum is over all the integer partitions of $n$ with $k$ summands.

Since $n_i\le n$, all the prime divisors of $\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}i^{n_i}n_i!$ are $\le n$, but actually apart from the single partition with $k=n$ summands $(n_1=n,n_i=0, i\gt1)$ and the single partition with $k=1$ summand $(n_i=0, i \lt n,n_n=1 )$ all the prime divisors of $\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}i^{n_i}n_i!$ are $\lt n$ because in these cases $n_n=0$ and $n_i\lt n$. Then, the denominator on the right hand side of the above explicit formula for $s(n,k)$ has only prime factors which are $\lt n$, then if $n$ is prime, it is also a divisor of $s(n,k)$.

From here I don't know how to complete the demonstration in the other direction..